# sql Left join giving duplicate multiple values

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

Friends I am unable to fetch correct result Please suggest , Thanks in Advance .
I have two tables and trying to get balance quantity

**One is Purchase Table  (purchase_detail)**

```
Pur_Date    Item_Id     Pur_Qty
2014-10-08  12792       25
2014-11-01  133263      20
2014-10-01  133263      2
2014-11-20  12792       10
```

**Second is Sale Table (sale_detail)**

```
Sale_Date   Item_Id  Sale_Qty
2014-11-17  133263     -6
2014-11-05  12792      -1
2014-11-24  133263     -2
2014-10-28  12792      -6
2014-11-05  133263     -2
```

**After using left join** 
**SQL** :

```
select a.pur_item,  sum(a.pur_qty  + b.sold_qty ) as bal_qty
from purchase_item_qty_amount  a left join  sale_item_qty_amount b 
on a.pur_item =b.sale_item  where a.pur_item IN( 12792,133263)
group by 1;
```

**Result - But it's incorrect**

```
Item_Id   Bal_qty 
12792     56
133263    46
```

**Result - It should be**

```
Item_Id    Bal_qty
12792      28
133263     12
```

Comment: I guess it should be `( sum(a.pur_qty)+sum(b.sold_qty) ) as bal_qty`

Comment: You gave us two tables but in your query you are referring to two different tables

Comment: You can not use a join for this case as it will aggregate all left rows to the right rows. Try your query without sum/group to see the raw data and you will understand what is happening: `select a.pur_item,  a.pur_qty,  b.sold_qty from purchase_item_qty_amount  a left join  sale_item_qty_amount b on a.pur_item = b.sale_item where a.pur_item IN (12792,133263);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested query:

```
select pur_item, sum(as bal_qty) from (
select pur_item,  sum(a.pur_qty) as bal_qty
from purchase_item_qty_amount  a
group by 1
union 
select pur_item, sum(b.sold_qty)as bal_qty
from sale_item_qty_amount b
group by 1)
group by 1
```

Comment: I'd use UNION ALL, just in case... (Also easier/faster to compute.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use union instead of join as the left rows have multiple matches to the right which cause too much data to be calculated. Try running your query without the sum and group by to see the raw data being calculated and you will see what I mean.

Your query with no group/sum:

```
select a.pur_item,  a.pur_qty,  b.sold_qty from purchase_item_qty_amount  a left join  sale_item_qty_amount b on a.pur_item = b.sale_item where a.pur_item IN (12792,133263);
```

Here is a query that works as you would expect:

```
select item, sum(a.pur_qty) + sum(a.sold_qty) as bal_qty from (select pur_item as item, sum(pur_qty) as pur_qty, 0 as sold_qty from purchase_item_qty_amount where pur_item in (12792,133263) group by pur_item union select sale_item as item, 0 as pur_qty, sum(sold_qty) as sold_qty from sale_item_qty_amount where sale_item in (12792,133263) group by sale_item) a group by item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full dummy of your question,try this one you will get your desired result:-

```
 purchase table

create table pt(Pur_Date date,Item_Id number, Pur_Qty number) 

insert into pt values('08.oct.2014',12792,25);
insert into pt values('01.nov.2014',133263,20);
insert into pt values('01.oct.2014',133263,2);
insert into pt values('20.nov.2014',12792,10);


 sales table

create table st(Sale_Date date , Item_Id number, Sale_Qty number)

insert into st values('17.nov.2014',133263,-6);
insert into st values('05.nov.2014',12792,-1);
insert into st values('24.nov.2014',133263,-2);
insert into st values('28.oct.2014',12792,-6);
insert into st values('05.nov.2014',133263,-2);


select purchase.Item_Id,(purchase.pur_qty+sale.sale_qty) bal_qty
from
(
 select a.Item_Id, sum(a.pur_qty) pur_qty 
 from pt  a 
 group by a.Item_Id
) purchase 
 left join 
(
 select b.Item_Id, 
 sum(b.sale_qty ) sale_qty
 from st b
 group by b.Item_Id
) sale
on sale.Item_Id = purchase.Item_Id
where purchase.Item_Id in (12792,133263)
order by 1;
```

Comment: Dear @GouravGarg if you find it correct then upvote it and accept the answer by clicking on correct symbol

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I get balance monthly e.g what was the balance in Sep, oct, Nov, dec in 2014.

Comment: Unrelated but: please don't rely on environment dependent implicit data type conversion. Using `'08.oct.2014'` will fail on installation that use a different `date_style` setting. The best (=most robust and portable) way is to use an ANSI SQL date literal: `DATE '2014-10-08'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i agree to you, it may be different date style ...but its what i use in oracle DB ..

Comment: @GouravGarg yes you can do by converting date into month and grouping them according to month then using lead or lag or row_number to add the previous month balance this way you can calculate the balance of every month